# To find whether annotation type is part of the covered text

Tags: uima, ruta

Sample Input file:

```
<p class="Head1"><a name="para1">Sections 87-89</a></p>
some text
<p class="Head2"><a name="para2">Sections 90-92</a></p>
some text
<p class="ParaFL"><a name="para3">Some Text1</a></p>
<p class="ParaFirstLineInd"><a name="para4">Some Text2</a></p>
```

For example from the sample input file, if I annotate "Sections 87-89 and   Sections 90-92" as Head1".Now I want to compare the annotation type(Head1) with its class type (  class="Head1", class="Head").If annotation type is not equal to class, then I want to set a feature "class changed" for the corresponding annotation type.Similarly for "Some Text1"  and "Some Text2" is annotated as ParaFL(annotation type).

Answer (score 0):

It depends on how the required information is represented. I assume that the class information is represented by the HtmlTypeSystem in Ruta.

There are two language elements missing in Ruta (2.4.0) in order to solve this. The main problem is that the attribute information of html tag is stored in two separate arrays and there is not option in Ruta to jointly iterate over them. the second on is autoboxing of types to strings.

I recommend to create an analysis engine (which can also be executed from within a Ruta script), which creates new annotations with one string feature containing the required information. Then, you can compare the annotation to the feature value. Autoboxing does not convert the short type names. I would add a feature to your annotations types with the corresponding type/class values. Then, you can compare the feature values.